# HTTP Error 405 - The HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed

Tags: iis

Can I make IIS serve a <form method="post"> from a static html file?

Answer (score 2):

If you are really asking can IIS serve ; meaning it responds to a GET request with a HTTP response containing HTML that happen to be from a file, then yes, yes it can and your issue is elsewhere.  I suspect you are asking something more complex however and would guide you to elaborate.

Comment: Thanks Ted.  If I change <form> to <form method="post">, it no longer works.

Comment: Well just for fun, not sure if this applies to you http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/TechOff/413392-IIS-ASPNET-Allowing-HTTP-POST